# isInvalidFragment passes wrong fragmentName after directory restructure

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am having an issue after placing my fragments into a sub directory with `isValidFragment` function.

All activities and fragments were previously under:

- app/src/main/java/com/myproject/settings/

They are now located here:

- app/src/main/java/com/myproject/settings/fragments/

After the move and placing `import com.myproject.settings.fragments.*;` in the SettingsActivity.java that is still located under settings/, isValidFragment is still receiving `com.myproject.settings.GeneralSettingsFragment`..
While my call to `GeneralSettingsFragment.class.getName()` is returning the correct `com.myproject.settings.fragments.GeneralSettingsFragment`.

See `isValidFragment` below:

```
    @Override
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || GeneralSettingsFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }
```

The error I receive:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myproject.settings/com.myproject.settings.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid fragment for this activity: com.myproject.settings.GeneralSettingsFragment
```

I have cleaned project and manually deleted build folder and rebuilt with no luck. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only to my future self..

Using Android Studio none of these worked :

- rebuild
- File->Invalidate Caches
- Delete .idea/ folder and resync project with gradle

What needed to be done was using the gradle menu ( or command line ) use app->Tasks->build->build. This uncovered many issues with renaming in the .xml files where they weren't updated with the correct path ( `com.myproject.settings.fragments.<fragmentName>` ).